# get element by id in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app, frontend using normal HTML&JavaScript and backend using Django.

I the frontend part, I have a table, which is supposed to pass the first column(title in my case) to backend upon select a row.

Now I have finished the select part but all the row of the table are passed to backend in innerHTML.

How could I get the first column(id=book_title) in the innerHTML?

```
              <table id="myTable"  class="gridview">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                     <th>Edition</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for book in page_obj %}
                <tr class="text_data selected_grey">
                    <td id="book_title">{{ book.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ book.edition }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".text_data td").on("click", function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    if(tr.hasClass("selected")) {
        tr.removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        tr.addClass("selected");
    }
});
          
            var elements= document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var j=0; j<elements.length;j++)
{
    (elements)[j].addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert(this.innerHTML); //now this one works, but show the whole row, I only want the first 
            var title = this.innerHTML.getElementById("book_title");

    alert(title); //this is what I want, but it does no work now
    });
}
        });

 </script>
```

Comment: Please note that you are duplicating your id `book_title` and that is a no no . ID's must always be unique

Comment: how to select the first one(title) without id?

Comment: Change your id to a class and find it by the class. Also if you google `javascript find child with class of element` you should be able to find many examples of this